# How to separate home page content from the rest of the pages in react router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-router-dom

I'm trying to create a react app with multiple pages, each with a different content indeed. I used (or at least tried to, because I guess that's the reason of the whole mess) react router. I wanted to put all the links into a bootstrap navbar. The problem is: when I go to another page from home page the content from the home page is reapeated above the content from another pages. Let's say my home page returns "Home" and about returns "About" then on /about both 
'Home" and "About" will appear. How can I fix this?

Navbar.js:

```
function Navigation() {
  const [collapsed, setCollapse] = useState(false);

    return (
      <Navbar className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" light expand="md" sticky="top">
        <NavbarBrand href="/">Home</NavbarBrand>
        <NavbarToggler onClick={changeCollapse} className="ml-auto" />
        <Collapse isOpen={collapsed} navbar>
        <Nav className='mr-auto' navbar>
            <NavItem>
                <NavLink href="/about" className="active">About</NavLink>
            </NavItem>
          </Nav> 
        </Collapse>
      </Navbar>
    )
```

App.js:

```
...
import {Route, BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";
...
function App() {
  return (
      <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Route path='/' component={Home}/>
          <Route path='/about' component={About}/>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use 'Switch' and `exact` with routes like this

```
...
import {Route, BrowserRouter, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
...
function App() {
  return (
      <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
           <React.Fragment>
             <Route exact={true} path='/' component={Home}/>
             <Route exact={true} path='/about' component={About}/>
           <React.Fragment>
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly

Comment: Can you please select this as the correct answer? Thanks.